# Meaning of "highlighted" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am not sure about the meaning of the word " highlighted" in the following sentence:

> A number of offers from the best restaurants, with set menus,
>   discounts and seasonal savings all highlighted.

The text is a description of the restaurant offers seen in the dining advertisements.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When something is **highlighted** is means that the whomever is highlighting is trying to draw attention to it.  It can either be physically

[image]

or simply a list if the best features of what's being highlighted.